# Android - Traversing firebase Database using snapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This is my database in firebase.
 [image]

This is my java code for traversing database.

```
 mref = new Firebase("https://social-axxxxxcf.firebaseio.com/user");
 mref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String email=userSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
        String urL=userSnapshot.child("url").getKey().toString();
         Log.e("Datas= ",email+" " +url);
    }


        }


        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Log.e("TAG= ",firebaseError.getMessage());
        }


    });
```

My problem is when i run this code my app getting crash and even error in log is not showing.
 Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `ChildEventListener` on `/user`, your `onChildAdded` will get called for every node *under*`/user`. This means you don't need t loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    String email=dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.classs);
    String urL=dataSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);
    Log.e("email="+email+" url="+url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link it's the working example to implement firebase with android.

[link](https://github.com/Adi1508/Android-Notification-using-Firebase-Real-Time-Database/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/aditya/fireapp/NotifierService.java)